# C++ function returns a value without checking else statement

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, return

I'm writing a tictactoe program and whenever i run the code and enter values such that the first if statement is true and the second is false the else statement is skipped and the function returns some integer and whenever i assign values as described above before running the code, it doesn't skip the else statement. the array shows how i represented the tictactoe board and it is a string array.

```
int check_diagonals(){

array[0][0]; array[0][1]; array[0][2];
array[1][0]; array[1][1]; array[1][2];
array[2][0]; array[2][1]; array[2][2];

string middle_array_value = array[1][1];

if(array[0][0] ==  middle_array_value)
{   
    if(middle_array_value == array[2][2])
    {
    //some code to return values
    }
}
else
return 1; }
```

Comment: Yes, if the condition of the nested `if` is false, the `else` on the outer `if` won't execute.

Comment: Read compiler warnings. Your code does not return on all paths.

Comment: Else statement is never meant to be "checked". It's basically a set of statements that will surely run when none of your `if` statement are true. Also the `else` will only run if the first `if` is false, it has nothing to do with the nested `if`.

Comment: Your description means it's working as written. Learning a bit more about branching and scope should help you understand this better.